# Using only 1 command line, how do I write a command to that will do a long list of all files in the storage/file directory

Tags: linux, unix

Using only 1 command line, how do I write a command to that will do a long list of all files in the storage/file directory and pipe the output to a grep command that finds all items containing the word pizza?

Would it be this?:

```
ls -l /storage/file | grep pizza
```

Comment: `echo storage/file/*pizza*`?

Comment: Are you intending to look for filenames that contain the word "pizza", files that contain the word "pizza" in the contents of the file, or lines of the `ls` output that contain the word "pizza" (which could include user or groups, or the filenames)? Here's a quick hint: whatever you do, the command will need to have the word "pizza" in it somewhere, which your current attempt doesn't.

Comment: I know you asked for `grep` but did you consider using `find` to search for the word pizza?  `find /storage/file -name pizza`

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
grep -l pizza /storage/file/*
```

This will print the names of all files under `/storage/file/` that contain the word pizza.

If you want the long listing of these files, you can do any of these:

```
ls -l $(grep -l pizza /storage/file/*)
grep -l pizza /storage/file/* | xargs ls -l
```

Comment: `grep` has two modes of operation: it searches for a pattern in files listed on the command line OR if no files are listed then it will search in standard input, which can come from a pipe. So, method 1: `grep pattern file1 file2` or method 2: `some_cmd | grep pattern`. The correct way depends on what you want to do.

Comment: You only need to quote when the pattern contains characters that mean something in the shell. For "pizza" `grep pizza` is fine, but for "a pizza" you would have to write `grep 'a pizza'`.

Answer (score 0):

There is always your friend the `find` command.

```
find /storage/file -name '*pizza*' -exec ls -l {} \;
```

Note the single quotes around the name to prevent the shell from expanding the glob too soon. This form has the bonus being easily adapted to also looking IN said files:

```
find /storage/file -name '*pizza*' -exec grep cheese {} \;
```

This finds all files named with pizza in their file name and then shows all of the places they  mention cheese.

Or did you mean just find all of the files talking about pizza in a directory and then long list them?

```
ls -l $(grep -l pizza /storage/file/*)
```